# numpy loadtxt reading numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy loadtxt to read some numbers(that represent X coordinate and Y coordinate)

I used Mac's TextEdit to write something like below

```
900 900
2400 900
480 2500
2900 2500
```

But when I tried to use numpy.loadtxt to read it

```
pts1 = np.loadtxt(upload('src_points.txt'))
```

I get an error saying

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>   '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200'

What am I doing wrong? I am using numbers instead of string..

Comment: Are you sure it's the same file?  What is this `upload`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's the same file, I don't know why it's thinking my numbers are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Mac's TextEdit saved the textfile in rtf format and that is causing this error. When I used SublimeText(a text editor), everything worked fine